# SharedFlow is not getting collected in previous fragment when another fragment is added on top

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Here is my MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            binding.fragmentContainerView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                addToBackStack(FragmentA.Companion::class.java.name)
                add(R.id.fragment_container_view, FragmentA.newInstance())
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the relevant fragment A code :

```
class FragmentA : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
    
    .....
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        fragmentABinding.button.setOnClickListener {
            parentFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                addToBackStack(FragmentB.Companion::class.java.name)
                add(R.id.fragment_container_view, FragmentB.newInstance())
            }
        }

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                viewModel.sharedFlow.collect { collectedString ->
                    Log.i("FragmentA", collectedString)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant fragment B code :

```
class FragmentB : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    ....
    
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.sharedFlow.collect { collectedString ->
                    Log.i("FragmentB", collectedString)
                }
            }
        }

        fragmentBBinding.button.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.setSharedFlow("Hello")
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my activity scope viewmodel :

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var _sharedFlow = MutableSharedFlow<String>()
    val sharedFlow = _sharedFlow.asSharedFlow()
    
    fun setSharedFlow(string: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _sharedFlow.emit(string)
        }
    }
}
```

I have my mainactivity, on the click of a button I add my `fragmentA`, then on click of another button in `fragmentA`, I add my `fragmentB` on top of `fragmentA`, on the click of a button in `fragmentB`, I am setting a shared flow in my `sharedviewmodel` and collecting that sharedflow in both fragments (flow should be collected in `fragmentA` even if it's in the background), but the collection in `fragmentA` is not happening, I have tried removing the `repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)` block and directly starting collecting in `fragmentA` like this :

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.sharedFlow.collect { collectedString ->
                Log.i("FragmentA", collectedString)
            }
        }
```

This seems to be working but I want to achieve this in a lifecycle-aware way recommended by Google, and since the lifecycle of `fragmentA` doesn't fall below the Destroy state

```
repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED)
```

should achieve this. I want to get others' feedback on why the flow in fragment A is not getting collected and how to do it in a lifecycle-aware manner as provided by the repeatOnLifecycle method.

Comment: I think you need to use ```repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)``` rather Created.

Comment: From the android documentation : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines - 
repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) ensures repeatOnLifecycle launches the block in a new coroutine every time the lifecycle is in the STARTED state (or above) and cancels it when it's STOPPED. So I'm passing Lifecycle.State.CREATED because, as per my understanding, this will ensure the coroutine will launch when lifecycle is in CREATED state and get cancelled when it's DESTROYED, since this is the behaviour I want.

Comment: I don’t think there is any way you can reliably do this because an instance of FragmentA may not even exist while it is offscreen. You can never expect off-screen activities or fragments to be active or to even exist when off-screen.

Comment: I think it's because FragmentA uses parentFragmentManager in adding FragmentB causing the former to be replaced/detached and consequently destroyed while the latter is onTop(added). You can set `replay` cache to the sharedflow(probably 1) so FragmentA will be able to receive the most recent emission when it resubscribe. Or you may want to use MutableStateFlow instead if the emitted value is a ui state.